# AWS profile issue: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to run a Kotlin project which utilizes AWS for authentication. I'm completely stumped on what this error is trying to tell me. I'm not sure if it's an issue w/ my AWS config or credentials or if it's an issue w/ gradle. Any insight would be much appreciated!

The project/code works fine on other PCs but I'm trying to get it setup on a new one.

[This is a screenshot of my config and credentials files in my .aws folder under my username](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QStYD.png)

````
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property cognitoUserPool has not been initialized
        at BaseUser.cleanup(BaseUser.kt:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:126)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:116)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:403)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:401)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1085)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:401)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:209)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:78)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:145)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:371)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337)
    at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
    at CognitoUserPool.<clinit>(CognitoUserPool.kt:15)
    ... 80 more
RegistrationTests > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at RegistrationTests.kt:34
        Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException at RegistrationTests.kt:34
1 test completed, 1 failed
> Task :test FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/*/*/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 9s
4 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 2 up-to-date
Collapse```
````

Comment: AWS profiles are stored in `credentials` and `config` under `~/.aws/`. There is no `.txt` extension.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my .aws folder. I apologize, I don't have the files as .txt extensions :/

Comment: For the selected AWS profile, do you have a region setting?

Comment: Yep the config is  ```output = json
region = us-west-2```

Comment: I'd be tempted to start with a very basic project that simply creates a client object (e.g. AmazonS3Client or AmazonCognitoSyncClient) and does some basic list or describe function. Can you get that to work with your credentials profile.

Comment: Are you using the `AwsClientBuilder` anywhere? That class isn't finding a specified region.
I'm not convinced that the AWS SDK is going to read your local `~/.aws/` folder at all, that doesn't seem like a sensible default or something practical when writing an application.